# Flyway configuration java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flyway.core.Flyway

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, flyway

I'm trying to connect flyway to my project which is using Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE version.
I found some solution here how to do it: https://blog.trifork.com/2014/12/09/integrating-flywaydb-in-a-spring-framework-application/
so I've made 1:1 like in the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
   <jpa:repositories base-package="main" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="main"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <!-- Flyway configuration -->
    <bean id="flyway" class="org.Flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
        <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true" />
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:db/migration" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="flyway">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="main"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"/>
        <property name="username" value="FITNESSAPPLICATION_USER"/>
        <property name="password" value="FITNESSAPPLICATION_PASS"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

with
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitnessapplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but `org.flyway.core.Flyway"` is marked on red and getting:

```
14-Dec-2020 16:32:44.204 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [DispatcherServlet]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flyway.core.Flyway
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1441)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:467)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:483)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1634)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: it should be `org.flywaydb.core.Flyway` instead of `org.Flyway.core.FlyWay`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `org.flyway.core.Flyway` instead of `org.Flyway.core.Flyway`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried with `org.flyway.core.Flyway` and later tried with org.Flyway.core.Flyway., nevertheless both does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used dependency as following (used in spring mvc/Boot without xml based configuration)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Created a class FlywayPostDeploy as following

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationInfo;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback;

public class FlyWayPostDeploy implements FlywayCallback {

@Override
public void beforeClean(Connection connection) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeClean");

}

@Override
public void afterClean(Connection connection) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterClean");
}

@Override
public void beforeMigrate(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeMigrate");

}

@Override
public void afterMigrate(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterMigrate");

}

@Override
public void beforeUndo(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeUndo");

}

@Override
public void beforeEachUndo(Connection connection, MigrationInfo info) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeEachUndo");

}

@Override
public void afterEachUndo(Connection connection, MigrationInfo info) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterEachUndo");

}

@Override
public void afterUndo(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterUndo");

}

@Override
public void beforeEachMigrate(Connection connection, MigrationInfo info) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeEachMigrate");

}

@Override
public void afterEachMigrate(Connection connection, MigrationInfo info) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterEachMigrate");

}

@Override
public void beforeValidate(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeValidate");

}

@Override
public void afterValidate(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterValidate");

}

@Override
public void beforeBaseline(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeBaseline");

}

@Override
public void afterBaseline(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterBaseline");

}

@Override
public void beforeRepair(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeRepair");

}

@Override
public void afterRepair(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterRepair");

}

@Override
public void beforeInfo(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("beforeInfo");

}

@Override
public void afterInfo(Connection connection) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("afterInfo");

}
```

}

And passed Datasource from bean class like this

```
    public void setFlyWay(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
    try {
        final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        final MigrationInfo migrationInfo = flyway.info().current();
        LOGGER.info(migrationInfo);
        flyway.repair();
        flyway.migrate();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Flayway Exception : " + e);
    }
}
```

and in resource folder as following with sql  as intend [refer](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#syntax)

[image]

Comment: in configuration file you have it all, I mean this setFlyWay?

Comment: Nevertheless I cannot use this flyweay-core version as it is too high for me.

Comment: Have you tried adding dependency 
    
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: Why should I add this dependency?